# Custom Cell merge in UITable view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

I am working with Custom cell merge functionality in my UITableView.

I have Table view with 3 different column. First column is for username, second is for Facility that is provided to user and last is for the permission that is given to user for the particular facility. And currently my Table view shows as follows:

[image]

As you can see in the above image the Username cell is repeating, if username is same for different facility. So it's not looking what I want.

I want to merge Username cell column to stop repetition. And want to merge cell as below given image.

[image]

I got count of Different Username which is repeat in database table with NSSet but i did not get clue how to merge this cell.

Please help me for this and provide some sample code for the same if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use section of tableview, but if you use section the username will be display on top, and under particular user all details will be available.

Comment: Do you mean merge by "[Marge](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Marjorie_Dursley)"?

Comment: Yes @NSNoob sorry for mistake.

Comment: it seems your are looking for using sections in a table view for _users_; and your cells' type is `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle`, where the top label is the _access_ the greyed label is the _permission_ – don't overcomplicate, iOS user will not expect seeing such a complex tableview on their devices' screen.

Answer (score 2):

TableViews are single column. You may have to use 3 TableViews to achieve your UI.

If you use 3 TableViews - all you need to do is set the height of the cells in the first tableview (User) as multiplers of number of respective rows in the second tableview (access).

For example, the height of 'User 1' cell would be 5 times the height of a cell in the second table (access). The height of 'User-2' would be 2 times the height of a cell in the second table (access).

Comment: If 3 tableviews are used then how to scroll all of them simultaneously?

Comment: Good question. The scroll needs to be synced. `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView` so you can set yourself as the `UITableViewDelegate` and override `scrollViewDidScroll`. You can set the `setContentOffset` of the other two tables to be in sync in `scrollViewDidScroll`.

Comment: yes that would be very difficult. We have to manage scroll from every table vice versa. Means scrolling from any of the table should effect in other two as well.

See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use a section. 
But still if you want to make `UI` like that, then the process is as below.

If you have data like in 2nd image then you need to **create 1 row for 1 user**.
Then you need to create 2nd and 3rd column, by dynamically. 
i.e. if User 1 has 5 row, then you need to create 5 **Custom view in User 1's Cell** programatically.

Then you need to **manage height of cell** also programatically.
i.e. if User 1 has 5 row, and you take height of 1 row is 50 then you need to make cell of (5 * 50) = 250.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this output by taking only single **UITableView**.

Create your UITableView as shown in image.

[image]

Follow below steps to get the desired result.

================================================

- Create a UITableView with dynamic row height. (using 
  **UITableViewAutomaticDimension**)
- Create a UITableViewCell as shown in image like Left side is **UIView** containing **UILabel** as **User**.
- Create UICollectionView for right part of your TableViewCell containing two 2 columns for facility and permissions.
- Disable scrolling for the **CollectionView**.
- Give **Height Constraint** to the UIView (UserView) created above.
- Now to populate your tableview:
- Get the number of count Facility for every user and set Height of the UserView as:

  ```
  facilityCount * CollectionViewCell item height
  ```

By this way you can achieve your output in very efficient way without any multiple scrolling issue.